# cloudfoundry NoHostAvailableException while deploying app

Tags: spring, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have deplyed my local cloudfoundry instance. When I try to deploy my application , my app requires cassandra to be up and running. I have cassandra host setup on independant server. Cloud foundry throws com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException

Whereas when I try to ping this host from the machine on which CF is installed , Ping is successful. Even this cassandra host is accessible from my local computer and works fine with my eclipse deployment.

How can I make cloudfoundry recognize this host?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that (a) your application has access to the information about the address and credentials to access the cassandra server, and that (b) networking (and maybe DNS) are such that your application instances will actually be able to reach the cassandra server.

For (a), you will want to bind your application to a "[user-provided service instance](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html)".  For (b), you need to make sure your application's running [security groups](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/adminguide/app-sec-groups.html) allow it to reach your cassandra server.

Comment: Actually new bosh cloud foundry makes security group mandatory.